What's the different between "unspoilt" and "pristine"?
A) Last weekend, I went to a pristine beach near my house. On the beach there is a beautiful hotel that is really in keeping with the local environment and looks great.
B) Last weekend, I went to a unspoiled beach near my house. On the beach there is a beautiful hotel that is really in keeping with the local environment and looks great.
I asked GPT, GPT told me option A is more correct than option B, but I asked my teacher, he told me option B is correct.
I explain shortly my understanding:

This two words all has the meaning of no changes.

a)  Pristine emphasises the property of origin, the beginning state.
b) Unspoiled emphasises no change, especially human-made, worse.


From the option A and B, there's a hotel -> environment good (no changes of environment)  -> original state -> pristine is better. Am I right?

The words are sometimes used in different senses: Merriam-Webster has examples of "pristine" referring to books and the lunar atmosphere, where "unspoilt" would be odd. But in this context, there's no real difference. Words can't be ranked on a simple scale where one is an 8 and another is a 6.

Oxford Languages gives unspoilt as one of the definitions of pristine!  (It sounds odd to speak of a hotel as being on the beach, as though it was built on the sands - anyway, I would think of an unspoilt beach as not having any buildings near it.)

Beaches tend to be unspoiled/unspolit than "pristine", a pristine beach suggests there are staff who take pride in their work and take extremely good care of the beach–which is possible on a private beach. An unspoiled  beach suggests the beach is not invaded by tourists,  there are no modern high-rise buildings, casinos, funfairs  etc spoiling the view.

There's a lot more where those two came from: 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.

@KateBunting Is a hotel on a beach any different from a house on a lake, a store on the highway, or a shop on the road? For on M-W has "in close proximity with:  a village on the sea"


In the future, if you have questions about learning English, especially about which words are idiomatic in certain contexts, English Language Learners is usually a better fit. 2. When you're uncertain about meanings, start with a dictionary, not AI. For best results, try several dictionaries. If they leave you still uncertain, feel free to ask a question here, but tell about what you found in the dictionaries and why it wasn't clear; that will give better answers. Please do that for this question to keep it eligible for answers.


I agree with your analysis of meaning but agree with your teacher's conclusion.
First, unspoiled:

Cambridge
Unspoiled: An unspoiled place is beautiful because it has not been changed or damaged by people
Unspoiled: Something that is unspoiled by another thing has not been badly affected by it

In both these meanings there is an implied potential for spoiling (by people or some other thing)
and for pristine we have:

Cambridge
pristine: new or almost new, and in very good condition
pristine: original and pure; not spoiled or worn from use

In both these cases there is an emphasis on new or original, with relatively weak recognition of the possibility of spoiling by people or other use.
In your example, the hotel may reasonably be expected to have the potential to spoil the beach (dog muck, litter, pollution, beach cleaning and other activities) so the word unspoiled seems more appropriate than pristine, which would merely be a statement that the beach is in its original state, without any consideration of the threat from the hotel.
